# mail function return true but mail isn't being recieved

Tags: php, email, xampp

Am sending mail from localhost.I've configured php.ini and sendmail.ini.
I've change php.ini file which now look something like this

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = ""D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"\\I've removed the backslash coming before D n I get true but when I use with backslash then mail function return false

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the D:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path = "D:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

sendmail.ini

```
  smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com    
 ; smtp port (normally 25)
  smtp_port=587
  auth_username=bsr.anwar@gmail.com
  auth_password=********
```

php code

```
            $subject = "Reset Password";
            $message = "To reset your Password please go to <a href='localhost/task2/reset_password.php?email=$to&reset_token=$token'>localhost/task2/reset_password.php?email=$to&reset_token=$token</a>";
            $headers = "From:bsr.anwar@gmail.com\r\n";
            return mail($to, $subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHPMailer plugin..
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
It's fast and easy to use.
You can get the documentation and tutorial [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial).